# Android ViewModel and Paging 3 Library

Tags: java, android, mvvm, pagination, android-room

I am building a chat app where every data enter in room database first and it's on data insert the recyclerview get update with new data. It works as expected but now i need to  update my paging library to version 3. For this i need to update these changes
as per [this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-migration) and [this](https://medium.com/@tantzewee/android-jetpack-migrating-from-paging-2-0-to-paging-3-0-c1caddad072d)

[image]

I have made all the changes but i am stuck at `viewmodel` class. I am not getting what changes i need to make in this class to make it work with the `paging library version 3`

This is my ViewModel

```
public class Chat_ViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public final LiveData<PagedList<ChatEntity_TableColums>> chatList;


    public Chat_ViewModel() {
        chatList = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(
                RoomDatabase.getInstance(MyApplication.getmContext(),1).chatDAO().getPaginationChat(String.valueOf(UserID())),20).build();
}

    }
```

In above class i know the `PagedList` and `LivePagedListBuilder` is deprecated but here i am not sure about the what to replace in updated library to make it work perfectly.

My room Database Query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tapChatter WHERE userName = :UserName ORDER BY ID DESC")
    PagingSource<Integer, ChatEntity_TableColums>  getPaginationChat(String UserName);
```

Issue facing:

1: How can i Update `ViewModel` for optimal performance for chat app? Is my current `ViewModel` is perfect for the chat app?

2: Is it possible to update the `RecyclerView` UI on Room Database data update ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully migrated from Paging 2 to Paging 3 and to be true its very smooth compare to paging 2 library with the help of `ViewModel` and `Room Database`. It was hard to find much documentation/tutorial for the java users so at last i found these links to get successful migration.
[Link 1](https://codingwithtashi.medium.com/android-paging-3-java-with-example-4efc9f9a2469)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230359/how-to-cache-pagingdata-in-a-way-that-it-does-not-cause-its-data-to-reflow)

These are the changes i made in my `ViewHolder` and `Fragment` for paging

Create Live Data in ViewModel

```
  public final LiveData<PagingData<ChatEntity_TableColums>> chatList;

public Chat_ViewModel() {
    Pager<Integer, ChatEntity_TableColums> pager = new Pager(
            // Create new paging config
            new PagingConfig(20, //  Count of items in one page
                    20, //  Number of items to prefetch
                    false, // Enable placeholders for data which is not yet loaded
                    20, // initialLoadSize - Count of items to be loaded initially
                    200),// maxSize - Count of total items to be shown in recyclerview
            () ->                 RoomDatabase.getInstance(MyApplication.getmContext(),1).chatDAO().getPaginationChat(UserID));
    );

    CoroutineScope coroutineScope = ViewModelKt.getViewModelScope(this);
    chatList = PagingLiveData.cachedIn(PagingLiveData.getLiveData(pager),coroutineScope);

}
```

Fragment

```
 viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(Chat_ViewModel.class);

        viewModel.chatList.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<PagingData<ChatEntity_TableColums>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(PagingData<ChatEntity_TableColums> chatEntity_tableColumsPagingData) {
                adapter.submitData(getLifecycle(),chatEntity_tableColumsPagingData);
            }
        });
```